# Objective C Button resize and delay

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I wish to re-size button at the place where it`s located and delay it, can you please help me?
(sender=UIButton)

My function:

```
-(IBAction)Animate: (id) sender
{

[sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Text Bg large.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CABasicAnimation *scale;
scale = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
scale.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1];
scale.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.3];
scale.duration = 1;
scale.removedOnCompletion = NO;

scale.repeatCount = 1;
[sender addAnimation:scale forKey:@""];
[sender setFrame:(CGRectMake(x, y, z, w))];


}
```

What do i use for x,y,z,w if i wish that button will stay at the same location, and grow 1.3 time larger without entering values manually. Oh, and how i can delay the this operation?

Comment: The animation is already scaling to 1.3 times larger, isn't it? What are you trying to do here exactly and what isn't working?

Comment: Yes, the animation is scaling it. But after animation ends it scales back to original size, and i wish to fix it at the new size after the animation.

Comment: Ah, right, understood. My Core Animation is rusty :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you're using `CAAnimation` to do this?

How about:

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectInset(sender.frame, CGRectGetWidth(sender.frame) * -0.15, CGRectGetHeight(sender.frame) * -0.15);

[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                      delay: 0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [sender setFrame: newFrame];
                 }
                 completion: nil];
```

or

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
                      delay: 0.5
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [sender setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)];
                 }
                 completion: nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
-(IBAction)Animate:(id) sender
{
  UIButton *btnAnimate = (UIButton *)sender;
  btnAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
  btnAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3f, 1.3f);

  } completion:^(BOOL finished){

    [btnAnimate setFrame:(CGRectMake(x, y, z, w))];

  }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how i setting the new position?

Comment: After animation, CGRectMake(x, y, z, w) happens. I need to put some value instead of x,y,z,w. I don`t wish to use CGRectMake(50, 50, 120, 180) as example. I wish it will be dynamic, that the button will stay at the same location.